# How to check if field value belongs to multi-select picklist with formula?

Tags: workflow, formula, workflowrule

I cannot save workflow formula with this line:

```
INCLUDES(Account.Categories__c, Category__c)
```

`Categories__c` is a multiselect picklist and `Category__c` is text field.

Error says:

> Field Category__c is a picklist field. Picklist fields are only
>   supported in certain functions.

And other try:

```
INCLUDES(Account.Categories__c, TEXT(Category__c))
```

Error says:

> Error: Incorrect parameter type for function 'INCLUDES()'. Expected
>   Text Literal, received Text

Comment: Why can you not save it? If you get an error message, always include it here verbatim.

Comment: @AdrianLarson just added

Comment: Formulas are rather limited. This is one of those few scenarios where you might consider a trigger instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The brutally inefficient workaround would be to check the categories one by one and use a text literal for each:

```
0 < CASE(Category__c,
    "Value 1", IF(INCLUDES(Account.Categories__c, "Value 1"), 1, 0),
    "Value 2", IF(INCLUDES(Account.Categories__c, "Value 2"), 1, 0),
    "Value 3", IF(INCLUDES(Account.Categories__c, "Value 3"), 1, 0),
    "Value 4", IF(INCLUDES(Account.Categories__c, "Value 4"), 1, 0),
    "Value 5", IF(INCLUDES(Account.Categories__c, "Value 5"), 1, 0),
    0
)
```

Answer (score 4):

Includes is looking for a specific text value. "text". That's the 'Expected Text Literal' part of your error. You're trying to pass off the value of a field as text and you cannot do that.

A better way to write this is:

Includes(multi_picklist__c, "value")

Help article describing it [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&siteLang=en_US&type=0)

> The text_literal expression must be of type text and enclosed in quotes. It cannot be a merge field or the result of a function.
>   Salesforce returns an error if any of the following occurs:
>   You do not provide a text_literal expression.
>   You provide an empty text_literal expression, such as "" or " ".

Comment: That explains why the error was encountered, but not a viable workaround. OP still needs to get `Category__c` in there somehow.

Comment: @Vladyslav Kushney what are you trying to accomplish? Maybe there is a different approach that we can do that does not use includes.